# How to extract logic containing async await and try catch to it's own file in express Node js

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch, extract

Below logic is working. I need it in my server file in React app. How do I extract this (or the most of it) to its own file, like `redirectHandler.ts`?

```
if (req.url.includes('foo')) {
    const GET_ID = `query ($url: String!) {
      page (url: $url){
        content {
          ...on Page {
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }`;

    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        query: GET_ID,
        variables: {
          targetUrl: req.originalUrl,
        },
      }),
    };

    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(process.env.ENDPOINT, options);
      const json = response.json();
      return json;
    };

    try {
      const result = await getData();
      res.redirect(`/my-page/?id=${result.data.page.content.id}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }

    return;
  }
```

I tried the following:

I create a file `redirectHandler.ts`:

```
import * as express from 'express';

import GET_ID from './videoRedirectHandler.gql';

const videoRedirectHandler = async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  if (req.url.includes('foo')) {
    const getData = async () => {
      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          query: GET_ID,
          variables: {
            targetUrl: req.originalUrl,
          },
        }),
      };

      const response = await fetch(process.env.ENDPOINT, options);
      const json = response.json();
      return json;
    };

    try {
      const result = await getData();
      res.redirect(`/my-page/?id=${result.data.page.content.id}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
};

export default videoRedirectHandler;
```

Then I call it in the server file like:
`videoRedirectHandler(req, res)`

But now I get this error:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
> to the client

In the not-extracted example (initial code), I fixed this issue by adding `return` to the end of the if-block. But in my `videoRedirectHandler` function it's not possible.

How to fix this?

**Update:**
Thanks to @bergi I created two separate functions, which are working fine:

```
// getPageData()

import GET_PAGE_DATA from './getPageData.gql';

const getPageData = async (targetUrl: string) => {
  const getData = async () => {
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        query: GET_PAGE_DATA,
        variables: {
          targetUrl,
        },
      }),
    };

    const response = await fetch(process.env.ENDPOINT, options);
    const json = response.json();
    return json;
  };

  const result = await getData();

  if (result.errors?.length) {
    throw new Error('Unable to parse json response');
  }
  return result.data.page;
};
export default getPageData;
```

Inside above function I created another function `getData()`. Is that necessary?

```
// getRedirectUrl()

import getPageData from './getPageData';

const getRedirectUrl = async (url: string, originalUrl: string) => {
  if (url.includes('/foo')) {
    const { content } = await getPageData(originalUrl);
    if (content.type === 'MyPage') {
      return `/my-page/?id=${content.id}`;
    }
  }
  return null;
};

export default getRedirectUrl;
```

Why did you used `url` and `originalUrl` here?

**Update 2:**
In the browser when requesting for a non-existing url (but which contains `/foo` in the url), it gives a blank screen now. In terminal it throws `new Error('Something went wrong');` from `getPageData()` function.

When I inspect `result.errors` it gives:

```
[
  {
    message: '404: Not Found',
    extensions: {
      code: 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR',
      serviceName: 'node',
      response: [Object],
      exception: [Object]
    }
  }
]
```

And in GraphQL playground it gives:

```
 "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "serviceName": "node",
        "response": {
          "url": "http://fooo/path/etc",
          "status": 404,
          "statusText": "Not Found",
          "body": {
            "message": "No route found for \"GET /fooo/path/etc\""
          }
        },
```

I think because the GraphQL query works only if the `targetUrl` is correct. In GraphQL playground it gives the same error when adding a non existing url.

How to fix this issue? It should return to 404 page or something like that and get out of this function. Below both functions:

**getPageData():**

```
const getPageData = async (targetUrl: string) => {
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: GET_DATA,
      variables: {
        targetUrl,
      },
    }),
  };

  const response = await fetch(process.env.ENDPOINT, options);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Unable to parse json response');
  }

  const result = await response.json();

  if (result.errors?.length) {
    console.log('foo', result.errors);
    throw new Error('Something went wrong');
  }
  return result.data.page;
};

export default getPageData;
```

**And getRedirectUrl():**

```
import getPageData from './getPageData';

const getRedirectUrl = async (url: string) => {
  if (url.includes('/foo')) {
    const { content } = await getPageData(url);
    if (content.type === 'MyPage') {
      return `/my-page/?id=${content.id}`;
    }
  }
  return null;
};

export default getRedirectUrl;
```

**Update 3:**
When I add `return { content: { id: null, type: null } };` inside if statement:

```
  if (result.errors?.length) {
    // throw new Error('Something went wrong');
    return { content: { id: null, type: null } };
  }
```

It works fine. Is there a better/cleaner way to solve this issue?

**Update 4:**
I fixed the issue by adding `try catch` inside `getRedirectUrl()` function:

```
const getRedirectUrl = async (url: string) => {
  if (requestUrl.includes('/foo')) {
    try {
      const { content } = await getData(url);

      if (content.type === 'MyPage') {
        return `/my-page/?id=${content.id}`;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  return null;
};
```

Comment: *"Then I call it in the server file like: `videoRedirectHandler(req, res)`"* Sounds like you're doing something to send headers before the async work is complete. Please show the route handler where you're doing the call. (It should have nothing else in it.)

Comment: @meez It means show the "server file" where you are doing the `videoRedirectHandler(req, res)` call

Comment: This looks like a nodejs web server (using express, maybe?), and has nothing to with react. Please remove the mention of "react app" from your question title and tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not extract the `if (req.url.includes('foo')) {` part, and particularly the early `return`, into the function as well. Keep that in your original code:

```
if (req.url.includes('foo')) {
  videoRedirectHandler(req, res);
  return;
}
```

The `return` keyword is crucial. It prevents the rest of your router handler function from running. You cannot move that into a different function and expect the control flow to be the same.

---

Alternatively, you can write a helper function that determines the redirect URL conditionally, and have your routing code use its result:

```
async function getPageData(targetUrl) {
  …
  if (result.errors?.length) throw new Error(…);
  return result.data.page;
}
async function getRedirectUrl(url, originalUrl) {
  if (req.url.includes('foo')) {
    const {content} = await getPageData(originalUrl);
    if (content.type === 'Bar') {
      return `/my-page/?id=${content.id}`;
    }
  }
}
```

These are two functions you can easily unit-test. Then in the server's request handler, write

```
const redirectUrl = getRedirectUrl(req.url, req.originalUrl);
if (redirectUrl) {
  res.redirect(redirectUrl);
  return;
}
…
```

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer. But now if I want to write a unit test for this file `videoRedirectHandler`. How do I do that? Since now the logic `if (req.url.includes('foo')` is outside of this file. Another thing. I can query another value from Page namely `type`. It will give the type of the page e.g 'Bar'. I want only `if (result.data.page.content.type === 'Bar')` run this function. Because now when I try another page type and add in the `url` -> `foo`. It keeps looping... How do I fix that with now this extracted file in place?

Comment: Well they're separate units so they should be tested separately. You can of course further extract a `shouldRedirectToVideo(req.url)` function that you can test separately.

Comment: If the redirect depends on the result of the fetched data, you should separate out only that. Make a `getRedirectUrl(req.originalUrl)` function that does the checks and returns a promise for either a url or nothing (`null`). Then `await` it in your route handler, and depending on the result do the redirect or continue processing.

Comment: I updated my question with 2 small questions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "*I created another function `getData()`. Is that necessary?*" - no. Just write `… if (!response.ok) throw new Error(…); const result = await response.json(); …` in `getPageData`. "*Why did you use `url` and `originalUrl` here?*" - because that's what you used in your original code. Not sure I understand the question.

Comment: one more question. When I test with a non existing url (which contains `/foo`), I get a blank screen and in terminal from getPageData() function it shows throw new Error('Something went wrong');. How do I get out of this function when url has `statusCode: 404` but also has `/foo` in the url. It should be send to 404 page or something? Thanks!

Comment: Inspect `result.errors`. If your (GraphQL) API tells you that the requested id does not exist (I don't know how exactly it does that), either throw a more specific error that your express error handler converts into a 404, or return a special object that the code at `if (redirectUrl)` tests for and sends a 404, or return `null` (as if the content has the wrong type) and let your remaining logic handle the case (likely with 404?)

Comment: I think because the GraphQL query works only if the `targetUrl` is correct valid/existing url. In GraphQL playground it gives the same error when adding a non existing url. How to fix this? I add the log of `result.errors` to my question. Thanks

Comment: when I add `return { content: { uuid: null, type: null } };` to the if block: `if (result.errors?.length) {
    // throw new Error('Something went wrong');
    return { content: { id: null, type: null } };
  }` it works fine. Is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do - if you actually want to forward the `extensions.response` to the client you'd have to set it up differently. Otherwise this looks fine. I'd maybe just `return { content: null }` and add an `if (!content) return` check in `getRedirectUrl` to make it more explicit. But either way, that just means your router won't do a redirect and continue handling the request in whatever way it handles non-foo requests - which may or may not lead to the desired (404?) response.

Comment: I updated my question. I fixed it by adding `try catch` inside `getRedirectUrl()` function. Is this the correct fix? Why do I need try catch here? Thanks